# sqlite3 commands to edit content in a table

Tags: database, sqlite

I can currently view the contents of a table in a database using sqlite3 commands.

```
select from table_name where table_attribute = some_value
```

However, I would like to be able to edit an email template, for example, in a table, or update a file stored in the table for attachments. I have GUI for this that runs on a Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10 desktop environment very well. But, for work-related reasons, I needed to install Windows. Now, I use VMs for Ubuntu Server 14.04 and have the software I created on it, written primary in Python, but can only run CLI commands. No GUI VM works very well on my cheap laptop.

I would like to use the command line to replace what I normally would do in the GUI, such as, add an email address a table in the database, edit an email template saved that is associated with an email address in the database, add or remove a URL that is in a table in the database.

I am not finding anywhere online how to edit content in a table in a sqlite3 database. I see how to select and count, delete data in a table, etc. But, not how to select a certain row or cell, if you will, and edit that field only.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: You're not very clear but you seem to be asking for the `UPDATE` statement. For example, `update table_name set some_column = some_value where some_other_column = some_other_value`. The values may need to be enclosed in single quotes depending on data types of the columns.

Comment: To clarify, the `some_other_column = some_other_value` is the value that updates the `some_column = some_value`, before `where`, correct?

Comment: It is the criteria for your query. If a record matches that condition, it will update `some_column` to `some_value`, otherwise it won't. If you didn't have the `where` clause, you would update every record in the table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This helps me quite a bit. I am running a vm on a very small laptop and the CLI versions of ubuntu seems to be the only virtual os fast enough to do the job. The app normally wants a web app GUI, but I found that I can also send sqlite3 commands to the database, and the software runs accordingly. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set column_name = "new value" where column_name "old value";
```

This successfully updated the information.

Thank you @topshot